# range.uncheck() in Google Script not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to have emergency notifications ready to send to my boss(es). I store these notifications in my Google Drive and send them using a script, triggered by an `onEdit` trigger. To prevent unintentional emails, I have a second "safety" checkbox that needs to be checked before the script will run. I want to uncheck the "safety" checkbox using the `range.uncheck()` method, but it's not working. I'm asking for help because I have other `uncheck()` statements that work great, and I don't understand why this one "safety" checkbox remains ticked after the script runs.

Here's my code:

```
function myfunction() {
     
     // Get active spreadsheet/source file
     var srcSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
     // Get the source sheet tab
     var srcSheet = srcSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  
     var DM1wk1 = srcSheet.getRange('N19');
     
     var safetyBox = srcSheet.getRange('K211');
     
     if (DM1wk1.isChecked() && safetyBox.isChecked())   {
          
                         // Create the new sheet
                         var tempSheet = srcSpreadsheet.insertSheet('tempSheet');
  
                         // Hide all gridlines in the new sheet
                         tempSheet.setHiddenGridlines(true);
     
     // *************************************************************************************************************************************
     
                         // Get desired data in the currently active sheet
                         var srcData1 = srcSheet.getRange('C9:K41');

                         // Copy and paste the desired range to copy from the currently active sheet to the new sheet
                         srcData1.copyTo(tempSheet.getRange(1,1),{contentsOnly:true});
                         srcData1.copyTo(tempSheet.getRange(1,1),{formatOnly:true});
srcData1.copyTo(tempSheet.getRange(1,1),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS,false);
     
                        
                          srcSheet.hideSheet();
     
    
     
                         // This section prepares variable info for an email
  
                         // Sets the recipient(s) of the email message
                         var emailAddress1 = "kl1990@mail.com";
    
                         // Sets the subject of the email message
                         var subjectPDF = "Current Schedule" + ".pdf";

                         // Sets the 'body message' of the email message
                         var bodyMessage = "Here is my schedule for this week";         
       
                         // This section converts the new sheet into a pdf blob

                         // Make the pdf
                         var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(srcSpreadsheet.getId()).getAs("application/pdf");

                         // Set the title of the pdf
                         blob.setName(subjectPDF);
     
     // **************************************************************************************************************************************
     
                         // This section assembles and sends the email
     
                         GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress1,subjectPDF,bodyMessage, {
                                  htmlBody: bodyMessage,
                                  attachments:[blob]     
                                  });
      
    
       
                         // Show hidden source sheet
                         srcSheet.showSheet();
     
                         // Delete new sheet ('Sheet')
                         srcSpreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
     
                         srcSheet.getRange('B1').activate();
                         
                         srcSheet.getRange('N19').uncheck();
                         
                         }    
     
                         srcSheet.getRange('B1').activate();
                         
                         srcSheet.getRange('R25').uncheck();
                         
                         srcSheet.getRange('K211').uncheck();
                         
                         }
```

}

Comment: Copying and pasting your code and commenting out everything but the checkbox stuff, it seems OK.  See if you can't break up your big procedural function into smaller sub procedural functions.  It's difficult for everyone (you, me, everyone) to pick out an error in a giant function.  [Follow the minimal, reproducible example guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and there's a good chance you'll see the bug as you try to refactor your code.

Comment: I included the entirety of my code (instead of a small piece) because,  since I was unable to find the cause of the problem, I couldn't be ]ositively sure that the cause for all of this was not in a far-flung (seemingly unrelated) piece of code

Comment: Sorry - typing on phone with fat fingers

Comment: I will follow the suggestions made and repost as needed. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Is there an error logged on the executions page of your script?

Comment: ----------No.----------

Comment: With the code provided both check-boxes are being set to FALSE as expected. Please be more detailed about what your "not working" means.